# Fatal error : Call to a member function getBackendModel() on null in app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer.php on line 425 M-1

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, csv, customer-csv

I got error while importing the customer using CSV in the admin.

Comment: Have you created any custom customer attribute?

Comment: yes, i have created 2-3 custom customer attributes.

Comment: For testing purpose, try importing the csv without those custom attributes.

Comment: If you are able to import the csv file without custom attributes, then there are chances that one or more custom attributes are not assigned to attribute set. You may need to fix that attribute.

Comment: Have you checked the import process without custom attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento checks all attributes in the CSV file before importing. And if there are some attributes that are either not assigned to attribute set or have no backend model defined, then Magento throws an error like the error which you are getting.

You need to make sure that your custom customer attributes are assigned to a set. Otherwise, the following code will remove your attributes from the array which will trigger the above error during the import:

> app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php

```
if (!$attribute->isInSet($setId)) {
    unset($attributes[$code]);
}
```

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Yes, i have removed the custom attributes from my CSV and its works.                 Thanks !!!!!